# Get method return type from an attribute of that methods parameter

Tags: java, generics

I have a class C with an inner Class attribute:

```
public class C{
   private Class<?> clazz;

   public void setClazz(Class<?> c){
      this.clazz = c;
   }

   public Class<?> getClazz(){
      return clazz;
   }
}
```

and I want do declare a method in another class so it's return type is that of C.clazz :

```
public class D{
    public <T> T getInstance(C c){
       //doesn't compile
       //some reflective code to set T to c.getClazz?
       return (c.getClazz.newInstance());
    }
}
```

so, for example, getInstance(c), with c having clazz set to `Class<B>`, would return me a new instance of B. Is there any way to do that with reflection?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class C<T>{
    private final Class<T> clazz;

    C(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public Class<T> getClazz(){
        return clazz;
    }
}

class D{
    public <T> T getInstance(C<T> t) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        return t.getClazz().newInstance();
    }
}


public static void main() throws Exception {
    C<String> c = new C<>(String.class);
    D d = new D();
    String s = d.getInstance(c);
    System.out.println("String = " + s);
}
```

This is also a classic way of storing generic type information. But I dont understand on why you would want `getInstace` method inside `D`. I would rather make it a static method inside `C`.

You can adapt a similar tactic even it was an array with `java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(t.getClazz(),10);` rather than just `t.getClazz().newInstance()`

There are even other ways to capture generic type information. [Read](http://purijatin.github.io/newsletters/generics/#NewInstance) this for more complex stuff.

Comment: Few notes : there is missing closing bracket for class D in the code. As for the C class newInstance() method it can not be static,  because the type will be determined on the C instance object. Also not every type `<T>` has non-parameter constructor, therefore it is better to make it outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

You need `getClazz()` and a cast to `T`:

```
public class D {
    public <T> T getInstance(C c) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return (T)(c.getClazz().newInstance());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class C<T> {
    private Class<T> clazz;

    public void setClazz(Class<T> c){
        this.clazz = c;
    }

    public Class<T> getClazz(){
        return clazz;
    }
}

public class D {
    public <T> T getInstance(C<T> c){
       //doesn't compile
       //some reflective code to set T to c.getClazz?
       return c.getClazz().newInstance();
    }
    public <T> T getInstance2(C c, Class<T> clazz){
       //doesn't compile
       //some reflective code to set T to c.getClazz?
       return clazz.cast(c.getClazz().newInstance());
    }
}
```

`getInstance` needs a C with T param, or else `getInstance2` would need a Class as parameter, and do an unsafe cast (you could add a check).